# Do two empty sets have any elements in common?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that two empty sets do not have any element in common since they do not have any elements in the first place.

Should I count $\emptyset$ as a common element?

Edited: two empty sets as: $A=\{\;\}$, $B=\{\;\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "*two*" empty sets?

Comment: They share none and all of their elements :).

Comment: There is only one empty set.

Comment: That's just *two names* for **the** empty set.

Comment: $A=\{\}$, $B=\{\}$, and $\varnothing=\{\}$. Two empty sets do not have any element in common. They do not have any element with any property whatsoever, as you observe.

Comment: "I think that two empty sets do not have any element in common since they do not have any elements in the first place. "  Correct.  Except they are both the same set.  "Should I count ∅ as a common element?"  Absolutely not!  Neither of those sets (that are both the same) have $\emptyset$ as an element.  So it is not a common element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. In particular, $\emptyset$ is not a common **element**, but rather a common **subset**. That is: $\emptyset$ has no elements, but is indeed a subset of itself (and of every other set!).

Comment: I chose this answer because it was most clear for me to understand. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 6):

Your argument looks good, $\varnothing\cap \varnothing=\varnothing$. In fact $\varnothing \cap X=\varnothing$ for any set $X$ !

Comment: ∅∩X=∅ does this mean that there is nothing in common? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @pigletwithcurls Yes, that is what it means.

Answer (score 3):

> I think that two empty sets do not have any element in common since
>   they do not have any elements in the first place.

Exactly.

> Should I count $\varnothing$ as a common element?

No, because $\varnothing$ is not an element of neither of the sets. It only is an element of their power set (i.e. a common subset), but the empty *set* is not an *element* of the empty set itself and therefore not a common element of the intersection between two empty sets.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ and $B$ do not have any elements in common.
$$
  \not\exists x: x\in A \wedge x\in B
$$

However, $A$ does have *all* its elements in common with $B$ and vice versa!

$$
  \forall x \in A: x\in B
$$
This is of course a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).